# IPv6 and AdvManagedFlag

Tags: networking, ipv6, rfc, configuration

RA messages have AdvManagedFlag. If this flag is ON then host "should use stateful autoconfiguration to obtain addresses" (RFC 2462). 
But RA messages are processing by the kernel. How do we know that this flag has came and host needs to run the dhcpv6-client? Is it provided? Do I understand the recommendation right?
In various implementation of IPv6-support (some routers, for example) I've seen the direct mode selection only (DHCPv6 or SLAAC) and I have not seen the dynamic mode selection based on flags from RA. 
And again: is it possible? Do I understand the recommendation right?
Hope for your help.